# How to make tds stack after sort using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, stack, jquery-ui-sortable

You can see the full problem here: http://users.cjb.net/syn4k/test.htm
I have described the problem in full at this location.

Edit: since you have asked to see the problem here as well,
Drag and drop the outlined items from one column to another and then try sorting the items in that column
Issue: The items do not stack after sort but rather, they align horizontally (float left or right). If you do not experience this problem try changing the td you are sorting.
Expected outcome: The items should always stack after sort and should never, in any case do otherwise.

Note that items should stack one item on top of another and not next to another.

Comment: It's important to also post the problem here because I would like to decide whether I can help you in the first place without having to click away from Stack Overflow. Moreover, if I were a malicious developer looking to drive traffic to my site, this would be a fine way to do it, so I find it hard to trust your question.

Comment: Are you supposed to be using a table as the element on which to base sortable? I also agree with Dave. I'd rather click on a jsfiddle link if you need to explain your problem visually. Either way, you should post a minimal version of your code here for posterity.

Comment: I did that 5 minutes before you posted :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how td's behave. If you want them to stack, each td will need to be wrapped in its own tr element. Your code might look something like this:

```
<tr class="gallery-block ui-sortable-helper">    
    <td id="4lveXTzn" >
        Nullam facilisis rutrum sem, eget pharetra dui gravida nec.
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Adam, Thanks for the heads up, it's too bad that's the only solution since that would make everything line up in a single column